# Getting code to run on all elements of list

Tags: python

Below is some code. The code itself does what I need it to do, but only does it on the first element of the "hand" list. I need it to do the same for the second element and add it to the total. I believe my running total code works I just can't seem to get it to run the code on the second card. (The elements represent playing cards btw.)

```
hand = ['JS','3C']


total = 0

for cards in (hand):
        
    
    card1 = hand[0].split(sep =',') ### Card 1 in hand list is split.

    card1_str = ' '.join(card1)  ### Card 1 is converted to string.

    card1_value = card1_str[0].split() ### Card value is stripped
    card1_suit = card1_str[1].split()  ### Card suit is stripped
        
        
    card1_value = ''.join(card1_value)
    card1_suit = ''.join(card1_suit)
    
    if card1_value == 'K' or card1_value == 'Q' or card1_value == 'J' or card1_value == 'T':
        total = 10
    elif card1_value == 'A':
        total = 11
    else:
        card1_value = int(card1_value) 
        total = card1_value
```

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through all the cards in your hand?

Comment: You're not even using `cards` in your loop. Just go through a Python tutorial and pay attention to the use of `fou` and `barre` in loops like `for fou in barre: ...`.

Answer (score 1):

you have hardcoded hand[0] inside the loop, hence it is running the below code only for the 1st indexed element in your list. Updated the logic and summed up the result gives 13 as output

```
hand = ['JS','3C']

total = 0

for cards in hand:  

    card1 = cards.split(sep =',') ### Card 1 in hand list is split.
    card1_str = ' '.join(card1)  ### Card 1 is converted to string.
    card1_value = card1_str[0].split() ### Card value is stripped
    card1_suit = card1_str[1].split()  ### Card suit is stripped   
    card1_value = ''.join(card1_value)
    card1_suit = ''.join(card1_suit)

    if card1_value == 'K' or card1_value == 'Q' or card1_value == 'J' or card1_value == 'T':
        total = total + 10
    elif card1_value == 'A':
        total = total + 11
    else:
        card1_value = int(card1_value) 
        total = total + card1_value
print(total)
```

output

```
13
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the variable you introduce in the `for` statement within the body of the loop to make it work as intended. Also, much of the formatting code is superfluous, because the cards are already strings:

```py
hand = ['JS', '3C']
total = 0

for card in hand:
    
    card_value = card[0] 
    card_suit = card[1]  
        
    if card_value in 'KQJT':
        total += 10
    elif card_value == 'A':
        total += 11
    else:
        total += int(card_value)
        
print(total)
```

Output:

```
13
```